# NSAppleScript Opens iTunes automatically

Tags: objective-c, if-statement, applescript, itunes

This shouldn't get the song name when iTunes is closed because iTunes has to open for it to check and return false.

Please Help.

```
//run applescript
NSAppleScript *script = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"try\n tell application \"System Events\" to set checkIfItunesIsRunning to (name of processes) contains \"iTunes\"\n if checkIfItunesIsRunning is equal to true then\n tell application \"iTunes\" to get name of current track\n else\n return \"No Song\"\n end if\n on error errmsg number errNum\n return \"No Song\"\n end try"];

NSAppleEventDescriptor *theResult = [script executeAndReturnError:nil];
//Set MenuItem
    [song setTitle:[theResult stringValue]];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might have better luck with something like:

```
if ([[NSRunningApplication runningApplicationsWithBundleIdentifier:@"com.apple.iTunes"] count] != 0) {
    // run your script
} else {
    // itunes isn't running
}
```

Comment: Man, I could kiss you right now! I've been pulling my hair out trying to find a solution for checking if an app is opened without needing the com.apple.systemevents entitlements that I had to use to check that from apple script. Thanks a bunch!